# Error: Argument 'Ctrl' is not a function, got undefined unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I'm having a hard time figuring this out. I'm starting to build my testscript. Even though its a little late. But unit testing is a good practice. For a start I just want to test two scope model (scope.global & scope.security) but I got a weird error saying my MainCtrl is not a function?

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('mainCtrl', ['LocalStorageModule'])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope' ,'$rootScope', '$location', 'Api', 'Security', 'Utils', 'localStorageService',function (scope, rootScope, location, Api, Security, Utils, session) {
    console.log('main js loaded');
    // $scope.main = {};
    scope.global = {};
    scope.security = Security;

    ....
}]);
```

My controllerSpec.js

```
describe('controllers MainCtrl', function(){

beforeEach(function(){
module('Services.api'),
module('LocalStorageModule')
});

describe('MainCtrl', function() {

var scope, api, security, session;
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller ,$location, Api, localStorageService){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $location = $location;

    $controller("MainCtrl", {
        $scope : scope,
    localStorageService : localStorageService,
        Api : Api
    });
}));

it('should create "usertype" model with empty list', function(){
    expect(scope.global).toBe(undefined);   
});
  });
});
```

Error result from above code:

```
Chrome 24.0 (Linux) controllers MainCtrl MainCtrl should create "usertype" model with empty list FAILED
Error: Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

I've tested my webapp on a browser and it doesn't encounter this MainCtrl is not function.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this correct?

```
angular.module('mainCtrl', ['LocalStorageModule'])
```

It seems like the module should be named something other than mainCtrl since that is what your controller is named.

In your test, you are not loading the module:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  module('Services.api'),
  module('LocalStorageModule')
});
```

Comment: wew, you were right I haven't loaded the module('mainCtrl') yet. That fix it!. Thank you very much for the help men. Now I can now go home, will continue my test script tom. It's now 11pm here. T__T. Thanks again.

Comment: oh btw, I think Angular is case sensitive so maybe its safe to assumed that mainCtrl is different from MainCtrl. Not sure though.